# Enterprise architecture

Tags: architecture

Let's say  you have to propose an enterprise system architecture. What would you take in to account in order to specify its structure, components, technology to be used, approaches to delivery it? How to start?

I just want to understand how the system architects work. To design for example a whole system is a massive work and how do they grasp it? How they know that what they propose is the right thing? How they know that this approach is better than the other?  etc.

Comment: "...ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical..."

Comment: Perfect reason to DV. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

An enterprise architecture is an architecture which spans across multiple systems, rather then focussing on the internals of those systems (technology) it defines which systems are used together so that one big system/process (might even say: a business) is formed.

I think what you mean is software architecture as Enterprise architecture can contain many things. As for software architecture design it is commonly documented in a Architecture notebook which contains (can contain more ofcourse, often does):

- Some sort of division (think of Packages in Java)
- A software deployment model (which displays (UML) and documents how the software should be deployed)

As for how they know what would be the right way to go about things. The architecture notebook comes before the functional and technical design and provides a higher level of abstraction.

By researching and evaluating existing solutions/implementations a good architecture can be made. This however does not mean they always know it is 100% right (though the abstract layer adds a lot of possibility for implementation).